# Can I have Custom Vision training data on-premises cloud instead of public cloud?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, azure-mobile-services, azure-cognitive-services

Can I have Custom Vision training data/images on-premises cloud instead of public cloud?

I have Microsft Azure cloud on-premises. Can I use and configure the same for uploading images on-premises Custom Vision server?

Currently I am using this URL- https://customvision.ai

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently Custom Vision service is available via [www.customvision.ai](http://www.customvision.ai).

Also, at the beginning of March, 2018 it was announced to be available on the Azure Portal in public preview, see: [Custom Vision service now available on the Azure Portal in public preview](http://www.vivien-chevallier.com/Articles/custom-vision-service-now-available-on-the-azure-portal-in-public-preview).

To answer your question, as of today, nothing has been announced for Custom Vision service on-premises.

Comment: That would be great to point to official MS links instead of your own site pointing to those official statements :)